# How to stake asset instead of currency?

Tags: staking, assets, pallet-staking

I would like to customize POS by staking the asset balance instead of currency balance.
After switching the consensus from PoA to PoS by changing AURA to BABE, I need to change the configuration of pallet_staking.
there are 2 fields in `pallet_staking::Config` need to be defined

```
impl pallet_staking::Config for Runtime {
    type Currency = Balances;// -> pallet_pts::Config::Kitty;
    type CurrencyBalance = (); -> pallet_potw::Kitty::Balance;
}
```

`Kitty` is defined in runtime : `type Kitty = Assets;` and `type KittyBalance = AssetBalance;`
However the trait of `Currency` and `Asset` is different, what should I do to able use this asset for staking?

Answer (score 1):

In [pallet-staking](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/f7306d327e0eee0a641ac43628ab525b0096ba7c/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L90) you can see that `type Currency` has to implement the `LockableCurrency` trait which is implemented for [pallet-balances](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/6579d6cce6dea8f2d9c5b39110fc393334363957/substrate/frame/balances/src/impl_currency.rs#L852).

Unfortunately this isn't implemented for `pallet-assets`. You could make your own `pallet-lockable-assets` by implementing the trait (if that is possible, didn't check) and use that for your Kitty pallet.